# How can PDO::execute return true when no insert happened?

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO::prepare() to prepare an INSERT statement. PDO::execute() returns true, and $dbh->lastInsertId() always has the next id, but no row is actually inserted!

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

if `$dbh->lastInsertId()` returns id from this very insert (i.e. no other inserts were fired), the row was apparently inserted. Just **double-check** your table. I mean it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to stab in the dark here and wager that you didn't run `$dbh->commit()` afterwards. Without the commit it will roll back the changes once your script ends or the connection is closed.

See also: [Transactions and auto-commit](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Comment: I thought perhaps this was the case, since the second insert has a foreign-key constraint that depends on the success of the first insert. I've added a `$dbh->commit()` after the first insert, and it does show up correctly, but the second insert still throws a foreign-key constraint error. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AlienBishop In that case you would need to give more details.